# How to call base class constructor in a separate UI thread

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, constructor, uiviewcontroller

I am in a situation where my base class constructor needs to be called in a separate thread(i.e UIThread). What i expect is something similar to InvokeOnMainThread(base()); instead of base()

```
Class BaseClass{
}

Class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   public DerivedClass : base()
   {
      ## Constructor
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest me any solution or workaround for this scenario.

Comment: this is a weird requirement. How has this scenario come about? Maybe your actual underlying problem is a design issue in your code structure. Hard to know without more context. But I strongly smell an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Let me explain the scenario. we have a class that runs from Non UI thread, but using UiViewController as base class. when we try to instantiate UIViewController from background thread, it throws UIKIt exception. For this we need to call UiVIewController constructor in UIThread.

Comment: why does the class need to inherit from a UI class, if it's not running as part of the UI? That doesn't, on the face of it, make a lot of sense. What does the class actually do?

Answer (score 1):

> when we try to instantiate UIViewController from background thread

**Unfortunately**, we can not instantiate the UIKit object in Non UI thread, and we also can not use the instance of UIKit.

If code is executing on a background thread, in a task or a callback then it is likely NOT executing on the main UI thread.

The error message will show something like as follows:

[image]

To fix these problems , generally we will use `InvokeOnMainThread` method.

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    // manipulate UI controls
});
```

**Otherwise**, you can send message to UIThread to deal with your wants. Such as using **[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)** .